# How does this snippet modify the object passed in?

Tags: java

I was doing a Java quiz and came across this question:

```
class Person {
    static int pid;
    int age;
    String name;

    Person(String s, int i) {
        ++pid;
        name = s;
        age = i;
    }
}

class Test {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Person p1 = new Person("John", 22);
        Test te = new Test();
        Person p2 = te.change(p1);
        System.out.println(p2.pid + " " + p2.name + " " + p2.age);
        System.out.print(p1.pid + " " + p1.name + " " + p1.age);
    }

    private Person change(Object o) {
        Person p2 = (Person) o;
        p2.age = 25;
        return p2;
    }
}
```

The answer turned out to be `1 John 25` printed twice, but I am confused as to how this happens. The value of the reference of the object `p1` is sent into the method `change`, but the contents are seemingly copied into a new object called `p2`. So where is `p1` actually modified?

Comment: as an aside, is it just me or are programming quizzes usually very humbling? :(

Comment: @Evil You are not alone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Person p1 = new Person("John", 22);
Person p2 = te.change(p1);
```

Now `p1` has his own fields:

`p1.age` is 22 and `p1.name` is `John`.

<sup>* The `static` variable `pid` is shared among all objects, in this example we don't really care about it</sup>

Now you call `change` on `p2`, let's see what's happening:

You pass the object `p1`, which is a *reference*, by value. You change `age` to 25, thus the original object will be changed. Now `p1` has it's `age` attribute set to 25.

Finally you `return p2;`, and it'll be assigned to `p2` in `main`.

Comment: Ah, the line `Person p2 = (Person) o;` merely copies the reference over to the new object p2, so any changes to p2 still gets reflected back at p1. Got it :).

Comment: For this question though: http://www.gocertify.com/quizzes/oracle/ocajp-java-quiz-1/Question-13.html I changed all the types from `int` to `Integer` but still got 22 on my IDE. Should it not be 24?

Comment: You're creating a local copy of that `Integer` in the method, note that you didn't changed any attribute of the class.. As soon as you exit the method the variable will be destroyed.

Comment: But did I not do the same in the `Person` example? Where is the difference and what could I do to make it display 24?