# Why is the output not changed in this code snippet when I use the object form of int?

Tags: java

Given this code snippet:

```
class Ex1{
  public static void main(String args[]){
  int x = 10;
  int y = new Ex1().change(x);
  System.out.println(x+y);
 }
 int change(int x){
  x=12;
  return x;
  }
}
```

I understand that the `x` in `main` won't get changed by the `change` method and return the value `22` because Java primitives are call-by-value. However, if I change all the `int` to `Integer`, making them objects and therefore theoretically call-by-value-of-reference, why does the program still return `22`?

Is it possible to modify the method `change` such that it also modifies the variable `x` in `main`?

EDIT: new snippet

```
class Ex1{
  public static void main(String args[]){
  Integer x = 10;
  Integer y = new Ex1().change(x);
  System.out.println(x+y);
 }
 Integer change(Integer x){
  x=12;
  return x;
  }
}
```

Comment: Why not? Your wording suggests you already know that it won't be "call-by-reference", so by what reasoning would the `x` in `main` change?

Comment: Where do you use the "object form of `int`"? Whatever you mean by that? Because I don't see any reference to `Integer` that is an object wrapper for `int` type

Comment: You're not changing the Integer that the *variable x* refers to, instead you're putting a new Integer into the *parameter x*, which is then put into y. So the *variable x* is unchanged. Also, you should have shown your code for Integers, right now I am just guessing at your implementation.

Comment: Am I blind or am I looking in the wrong place? Where is the `Integer`?

Comment: @GermannArlington "However, if I change all the int to Integer...", I guess I should've been more clear! updated answer now.

Comment: `Integer` as most of other classes is immutable...

Comment: And everything is passed by value in Java

Comment: These two statements can explain everything if you think about it

Comment: @GermannArlington objects are pass-by-value of reference, are they not?

Comment: @EvilWashingMachine Yes, which means that in `change(Integer x)` you are passing value to *local reference* of method `change` also named `x` which will hold this value. Assigning new value to this `x` can't affect reference `x` in `main` method.

Comment: @Pshemo but then what is going on in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26978397/how-does-this-snippet-modify-the-object-passed-in?

Comment: What do you mean? In that question `change(Objec o)` changed state (value of age *field*) of object, not reassign new value to object (original reference still holds same Person, its age was just changed). Assigning new value to variable, and changing state of object held by variable are two different things. For instance via `final List<String> words = new ArrayList<>();` I still can change state of list held by `words` reference like `words.add("foo"); words.add("bar")`, but I **can't** reassign new value to `words` with `words = new ArrayList<>();`

Comment: That is the difference between mutable and immutable objects.

`x = 10;` is basically equivalent to `x = new Integer(10);` (with auto-boxing) in fact replacing the reference with new object and because you only passed a copy of your object reference to a method it does not affect the original object

Comment: @GermannArlington yeah I was wondering whether it was because of the nature of immutable wrapper or whether I've actually modified the original reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both value and reference types are passed by-value in Java (see the [Java Tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/arguments.html)). This means that the passed-in reference still points at the same object as before the call, even if the internals of a method change the reference assigned to a method's parameter variable.

The [primitive wrappers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberclasses.html) are all reference types, so there is no difference between their behaviour and the behaviour of any other reference type when passed as an argument to a method.

However, you can change the *values* inside a reference object, and those changes will be reflected after the method call completes, in the calling method. You can't do this with the primitive wrappers though: they are immutable.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    Foo parentFoo = new Foo(1);
    System.out.println(parentFoo);  // prints "instance 1, data is now 1"
    changeReferenceFail(parentFoo); // prints "instance 2, data is now 2"
    System.out.println(parentFoo);  // prints "instance 1, data is now 1"
    mutateReference(parentFoo);     // prints "instance 1, data is now 3"
    System.out.println(parentFoo);  // prints "instance 1, data is now 3"
}
private static void changeReferenceFail(Foo myFoo) {
    myFoo = new Foo(2); // assigns a new object to the myFoo parameter variable
    System.out.println(myFoo);
}
private static void mutateReference(Foo myFoo) {
    myFoo.setData(3); // changes the reference variable internals
    System.out.println(myFoo);
}
...
class Foo {
    private static int iidSeed = 0;
    private int iid = 0;
    private int data;
    public Foo(int data) { 
        this.data = data; 
        this.iid = ++iidSeed;
    }
    public void setData(int data) { this.data = data; }
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("instance %d, data is now %d", this.iid, this.data);
    }
}
```

You asked: "*Is it possible to modify the method change such that it also modifies the variable x in main?*".

You can either pass a reference object, and modify an internal field (as per `mutateReference` above). Or you can return a new integer and assign it to your local variableexactly as you are doing already.

Comment: I am confused because in this question, the object gets changed: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26978397/how-does-this-snippet-modify-the-object-passed-in

why not the same here?

Comment: @EvilWashingMachine. In that question the *parameter* `o` was not reassigned. It was *cast* to a `Person` instance, and then *mutated* (similar to  `mutateReference` in my sample). At no point in that question do you see a line that does `o = new Person();`

Comment: So can I modify the method `change` such that it changes the value `x` in main?

Comment: @EvilWashingMachine. I added a new code sample which should help clarify. Look at the way it prints instance `iid`s to help you see when a new *instance* is created, and it also prints the values of `data` so you can see when the internal data of the object is mutated.

Comment: @EvilWashingMachine. No. Only if you pass an object with an integer value as an internal field. Or, if you *return* an integer value from your method `change` and assign it to the original local variable.

Answer (score 1):

```
Integer change(Integer x){
    x=12;
    return x;
}
```

Because this does not change what is stored *inside* the object `Integer x`, but assigns a new value to the variable `x`. It is not the original argument object being changed, but a new `Integer` object is created assigned to the variable formerly holding the original object.

Answer (score 1):

As you said, when passing an object to a function, you actually pass the value of its reference. Thus, statements like `myParam = something` have no effect on the object passed to the method, only method calls such as `myParam.mutate()` can change its state. Nevertheless, `Integer` is an immutable class so you will not be able by any mean, to change the value of the `Integer` in the main.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing the value of x to your method, that applies that value to another variable x. You would need to modify the correct instance of x to change it in `main`. This snippet changes x, although I'm sure you knew how to do this already.

```
class Ex1{
    int x = 10;
    public static void main(String args[]){
        System.out.println(x);
        changeX(15);
        System.out.println(x);
    }

    void changeX(int newVal){
         x=newVal;
    }
}
```